# Append child in the middle

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I would like to add an element to an XML file using minidom from python.
Let's assume i have the following xml file

```
<node-a>
    <node-1/>
    <node-2/>
    <node-3/>
<node-a/>
```

in this case i can easily append an element "node-4" as follow

```
node4 = designDOM.createElement('node-4')
nodea.appendChild(node4)
```

resulting with the following xml:

```
<node-a>
    <node-1/>
    <node-2/>
    <node-3/>
    <node-4/>
<node-a/>
```

my questrion is: if I would like to force the insertion of an element in a specific position instead of in the end... what should i do? for instance if i want an element "2-a" as in the following xml what shold i do?

```
<node-a>
    <node-1/>
    <node-2/>
    <node-2a/>
    <node-3/>
    <node-4/>
<node-a/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`insertBefore()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.insertBefore):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

data = """<node-a>
    <node-1/>
    <node-2/>
    <node-3/>
</node-a>"""

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data)
node_a = dom.getElementsByTagName('node-a')[0]

node_4 = dom.createElement('node-4')
node_a.appendChild(node_4)

node_3 = dom.getElementsByTagName('node-3')[0]
node2_a = dom.createElement('node-2a')
node_a.insertBefore(node2_a, node_3)

print dom.toprettyxml()
```

prints:

```
<node-a>
    <node-1/>
    <node-2/>
    <node-2a/>
    <node-3/>
    <node-4/>
</node-a>
```